# Antlr4, C# - How to check trigger within the more global listener?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm overriding some listener methods. I've got several objects which corresponds the following grammar:

```
object : BEGIN o1+ END ;
o1 : ( Token1 | (name | Token2 ) );
```

Here is the code from the EnterObject() override method:

```
if (context.o1(1).name() != null)
{
 object.Field = context.o1(1).name().GetChild(0).GetText();
}
else
{
 object.Field = context.o1(1).Token2().GetText();
}
```

It works, though I have some doubts. Is there more efficient way of checking the EnterName() within the EnterObject() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `context.o1(1).GetText()` instead of the longer expression.

I also recommend you add an attribute to the method where you use this code to declare the dependency on the descendants of `o1` (since those descendants implicitly define the result of the `GetText()` call).

```
[RuleDependency(
    typeof(YourParserType),
    YourParserType.RULE_o1,
    0,
    Dependents.Descendants)]
```

You can validate all uses of this attribute by calling the following during your application or library initialization code.

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(YourListenerClass).Assembly;
RuleDependencyChecker.CheckDependencies(assembly);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Currently I've overridden the methods using the long "context.o1(1).name().GetChild(0).GetText()"-like calls. It works properly, so I decided not to declare any dependencies.